# Unable to load rjags

Tags: jags

I'm having the following error when trying to load `rjags`. I recently upgraded to OSX El Capitain and also installed the latest version of JAGS 4.0.1.  Does any one know how to fix it?

```
 library(rjags)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:
  call: dyn.load(file)
  error: unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/JAGS/modules-3/bugs.so':
  dlopen(/usr/local/lib/JAGS/modules-3/bugs.so, 6): Symbol not found: _R_finite
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/JAGS/modules-3/bugs.so
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libjrmath.0.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/JAGS/modules-3/bugs.so
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rjags’
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by installing the development version of the `rjags` package.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/rjags/4/